# Dial number in iOS really need confirmation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I am using the following code to dial number and testing with my device. It seems **no confirmation** is needed, correct?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://12345678"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Please change the accepted answer since the second solution is way cleaner (e.g. localizing the message) and I didn't notice it on time :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Confirmation isn't required and isn't shown when done programmatically. You will only see the alertView in Safari if a number is clicked.

However, in my own experience, I believe it's more convenient for the customer to see a dialog box so they don't accidentally call someone. People just tap things in apps without even thinking and that could be bad in this case.

To mimic what safari does you can do something like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Call 12345678?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
[alert show];
alert.tag = 1;
[alert release];
```

and

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    switch (alertView.tag) {
        case 1:
            if (buttonIndex == 1) {
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://12345678"];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `+[UIApplication sharedLibrary]` method exists?

Comment: It should be `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

Answer (score 18):

An alternative to the suitable solution already posted, you could consider using the `telprompt` URL scheme, e.g.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString@"telprompt://12345678"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: +1 Although completely undocumented, in my tests it seems to work all the way back to iOS 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmation isn't required but it's desirable as it prevents confusion when users are dropped into the dialing application. one thing that you can do that was suggested by another answer is to use telprompt rather then just tel. This will provide the prompt that's necessary via a simple dialog. It also has a very nice side-effect of dropping users back into the calling application after the phone call is complete.  This key elements allows you to keep going rather then getting kicked out of your app.

A category that further explains this code and a sample project is available here:
http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/04/getting-the-best-behavior-from-phone-call-requests-using-tel-in-an-ios-app/